# @ModelAttribute, Why If don't work?

Tags: java, spring, post, modelattribute

My question is why don't enter into if when `acc.getUsername` equals `"stringExample"`? When I print `acc.getUsername()` this line ealier it shows its equals but dont go into if, why?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView checker(@ModelAttribute(value="acc") Account acc) {

        System.out.println(acc.getUsername());
        if(acc.getUsername() == "stringExample"){
            System.out.println("aaa");
        }

        ModelAndView model2 = new ModelAndView("index.jsp");
        return model2;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Java when you want to compare Strings contents you should compare them using equals() method:

```
acc.getUsername().equals("stringExample")
```

Comment: stupid me, thank you. it helps ;)